# How to build libpcap source for static lib and headers only

Tags: static-libraries, pcap, libpcap

I have source for libpcap and I want to build static lib and headers for my linux platform.
I tried with ./configure and make command but it is not generating lib and headers.

Anyone does know the configure cmd for doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: Command `sudo apt-get install libpcap0.8-dev` should do the job.

Answer (score 3):

At least on Ubuntu 10.0.4.2 LTS, building the [latest libpcap release](http://www.tcpdump.org/beta/libpcap-1.2.0rc1.tar.gz) produces both the shared and static libraries.

```
$ wget http://www.tcpdump.org/beta/libpcap-1.2.0rc1.tar.gz
$ tar xf libpcap-1.2.0rc1.tar.gz && cd libpcap-1.2.0rc1
$ ./configure && make
$ find -name "libpcap.so*" -o -name "libpcap.a"
./libpcap.a
./libpcap.so.1.2.0
```

Information about your specific build environment would be necessary to further answer the question, e.g. Linux distribution, version of libpcap.